# Overlay table cells with two buttons on hover

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a table as viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/chapmand/7c7SZ/10/

Essentially, its a calendar. What I want to add to it is, when I mouse over a cell of the table I want an overlay on the cell. The overlay should fill the cell, be transparent, and be split down the middle so that I can make the left side clickable and the right side clickable separately.

The major issue I have been having is getting the overlay to position properly because of the number that is in each cell. The number displaces the overlay so that and breaks the layout. The number should be in the top right corner of each cell.

I have been working on this for a few hours with no success. Any suggestions on what the structure of the data inside each cell should look like and what I need to do with the css to make it display the way I want?

Comment: First you should fix your `<<` and `>>` in the header to use `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your `<abbr>` elements in the upper right corner, you want to use `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0` but that would require `position: relative` on the `<td>`; the problem is that not all browsers will allow `position: relative` on a table cell so so you have to wrap the table cell's content in a `<div>`:

```
<td>
    <div class="td-hack">
        <abbr>11</abbr>
    <div>
</td>
```

And then this (with borders and background colors for illustrative purposes only) will put everything in the right place:

```
td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.td-hack {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
abbr {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

The same sort of `position: absolute` trickery will work for your overlay:

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="o-left"></div>
    <div class="o-right"></div>
</div>
```

And style it with something like this:

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #dfd;
}
.o-left,
.o-right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.o-left {
    background: #dff;
}
.o-right {
    background: #ffd;
}
```

Then you just need to append the overlay to `.td-hack` when the hover starts and remove it when the hover ends; this example uses jQuery to avoid the noise of a raw JavaScript solution:

```
var overlay = '<div class="overlay">'
            + '<div class="o-left"></div>'
            + '<div class="o-right"></div>'
            + '</div>';
$('td').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('.td-hack').append(overlay);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).find('.overlay').remove();
    }
);
```

A live demo of the technique: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ah5s3/1/

Comment: This looks exactly like what I am trying to accomplish. One question though. Is the javascript that is used to add the overlay necessary? Why can't the overlay be in the markup, hidden through css, and displayed on hover?

Comment: @chapmand: You should be able to do it all in HTML/CSS. Just seemed simpler in JS than messing around with extra HTML for each cell, `z-index` issues, etc.

Comment: ok, well I think the javascript will do. It just means that I will have to deal with unbinding the hover after one of the halves is clicked, but that isn't a big deal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I [**updated your fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7c7SZ/12/) with a decent way to accomplish this.  Here's what I did:

- changed `<<` and `>>` to `&lt;&lt;` and `&gt;&gt;`
- corrected a typo in your CSS for `vertical-align`
- added `position: relative` to the CSS for your `tbody td`
- Used the following pure Javascript (no jQuery needed) and CSS to add an absolutely positioned div on hover:

---

```
var day = document.getElementsByClassName('day'),
    daymouseover = function(e) {
        var elem = document.getElementById('dayhover'),
            skip = /otherMonth/.test(this.className),
            left, right;
        if (!skip) {
            if (!elem) {
                elem = document.createElement('div');
                left = document.createElement('div');
                right = document.createElement('div');
                elem.id = 'dayhover';
                left.className = 'left';
                right.className = 'right';
                elem.appendChild(left);
                elem.appendChild(right);
            }
            this.appendChild(elem);
            elem.style.display = 'block';
        }
    },
    daymouseout = function(e) {
        document.getElementById('dayhover').style.display = 'none';
    };

for (var i = 0, il = day.length; i < il; i++) {
    day[i].onmouseover = daymouseover;
    day[i].onmouseout = daymouseout;
}
```

---

```
#dayhover {
    width:80px;
    position:absolute; left:20px; top:40px;
}
#dayhover .left, #dayhover .right {
    float:left;
    opacity:0.5;
    padding:15px;
}
#dayhover .left {
    background:lime;
}
#dayhover .right {
    background:pink;
}
```

---

You will have to adjust the CSS and hover contents as needed, and also implement a cross-browser version of `getElementsByClassName`.  Good luck!

Again, [here's the example implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/7c7SZ/12/).

Comment: +1 for effort, but try hovering in Firefox. See @mu is too short's answer.

Comment: Yep, need to add his `.td-hack` for `position: relative`, otherwise this flies.  Thanks for pointing it out, was lazy about cross-browser testing.