# How to add overlay to material UI table row?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html-table, material-ui

I am rendering a row like this

```
`<TableRow
  key={row.name}
>
  <TableCell>{row.empId}</TableCell>
  <TableCell>{row.userId}</TableCell>
  <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
  <TableCell>{row.hireDate}</TableCell>
  <TableCell>{row.terDate}</TableCell>
  <TableCell>{row.empType}</TableCell>
  <TableCell>
    <Typography variant="button" color={row.empStatus ? 'primary' : 'error'}>
      {row.empStatus ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}
    </Typography>{' '}
  </TableCell>
  <TableCell align="right">
    <IconButton aria-label="view log" onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>
      <HistoryIcon fontSize="small" />
    </IconButton>
    <IconButton aria-label="edit">
      <EditIcon fontSize="small" />
    </IconButton>
  </TableCell>
  <div className="overley">
    <p>overlay text</p>
  </div>
</TableRow>`
```

and an overlay has CSS like

```
`.overley {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tableRow {
    position: relative;
  }`
```

I am expecting something like this
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYhpm.png)

so how to add overlay effect or any div which display over the row without effecting table or row width and alignment.

above code is adding one more column at the end, if I give left : 0, it's shifting to the left of the screen. Does anyone know how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do the same and was able to do this by doing the following more or less:

```
<TableRow className={'row-overlay-hover'}>
    <TableCell/>
    ...
    <TableCell/>
    <TableCell>
        <div className={'overlay-wrapper'}>
            <div className={'overlay-content'}>
                Overlay content
            </div>
        </div>
    </TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

```
.row-overlay-hover td:last-child {
    width: 0;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.row-overlay-hover:hover .overlay-content {
    visibility: visible;
}
.overlay-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.overlay-content {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Note:

- I referenced this [Overlay table cells with two buttons on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886103/overlay-table-cells-with-two-buttons-on-hover) and it's answer notes that not all browsers support `position: relative` on a table cell (though it's from 2012) so I opted to wrap my overlay in a div with a zero-width column at the end of the table